# Should we have an [unreliable-narrator] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So, I recently asked a [question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14989/is-calvin-an-unreliable-narrator) about whether a specific character could be considered an "unreliable narrator." I did notice that we now have a number of questions about this. That being said, can this be considered an actual topic that someone might have knowledge of? That being the case, should we create a tag for this? Or is this too "meta"?

Put another way, would anyone be interested in being able to easily find questions specifically about unreliable narrators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, we already have an [unreliable-narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreliable-narrator) tag, which was created on 28 November 2017, and which currently has four questions. We also have a [narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator) tag, which was created on the same day and which currently has three questions.

Looking back at this, I think that [narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator) should be sufficient. There are many kinds of narrations—first person, second person, third person, omniscient third person, first person plural, etc.—and I doubt we would want to create a specific tag for each.

Narrators are one aspect of literature that can be studied in the context of [narratology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narratology), but I wouldn't create a [narratology](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narratology) tag for narrators. If we were to create such a tag at all, it would be for questions about the *study* of narrative structures.

So why don't we synonymise or merge the tags [unreliable-narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreliable-narrator) and [narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator)?

---

Update: The [unreliable-narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreliable-narrator) tag was synonymised with the [narrator](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrator) tag on 19 August 2020.

Comment: After removing the tag from [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3175/17) which isn't about narrators as such, I've gone ahead and merged `unreliable-narrator` into `narrator`. The three affected questions were [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8005/17), [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8354/17), and [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13714/17).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Excellent. Thanks.